# Controlling keyboard's backlight in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, dell-latitude, backlight

Is there anyway I can control keyboard's backlight? In Windows 10 in general or for my Dell Latitude 7290 in particular?

My Dell has a great keyboard's backlight feature, but it turns it off after only 10 seconds since last key is pressed.

10-15 seconds is by far too short for me. It causes a terrible eye discomfort, when using computer in darkness. If only I pause typing for a short moment, everything goes black. And once I resume typing, I am hit with lights.

I cannot verify this right now, but I am pretty much sure that my Lenovo notebook turns off keyboard backlight after at least 30 seconds, if not 60 seconds after last key was pressed. And such eye effect / problem does not occur.

My current research:

1. I cannot control this via keyboard's hardware -- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> only controls whether backlight is turned off or the level of intensity, but not the auto-turn off timer.
2. I found nothing in Windows 10's keyboard configuration corresponding to backlight.
3. I have no Dell-related software installed on my laptop. If fact, the only Dell-related software that I can find when I type "Dell" in Start Menu is Dell Command Update that, again, has nothing either for backlight of keyboard or for the laptop configuration in general -- it only updates drivers.

Is there any way I can control this?

Comment: It should be in the System Configuration options according to the [user manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukbsdt1/latitude-12-7290-laptop/latitude_7290_om/system-configuration-screen-options?guid=guid-d6f5377f-d831-4f94-befe-74693de8cf12&lang=en-us)

Comment: One of the options is "Never" timeout.

Comment: Thanks, Jackpot! I'll craft a corresponding answer myself this time. Normally I'd suggest you to do this, but I am so shame that I failed to perform the most obvious check -- user manual -- prior to asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Latitude 7290's user manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/pl/pl/plbsdt1/latitude-12-7290-laptop/latitude_7290_om/system-configuration-screen-options?guid=guid-d6f5377f-d831-4f94-befe-74693de8cf12&lang=en-us), you must dig your way out to the BIOS. To do this, either press <kbd>F2</kbd> and hold it or key pressing it quickly until you see BIOS loading screen. [The window to enter BIOS on a Dell is short and you can easily miss it](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-enter-bios-on-a-dell-latitude).

When in BIOS, go to *Settings > System Configuration* and adjust values of:

- Keyboard Backlight Timeout on AC
- Keyboard Backlight Timeout on Battery

options to suit your needs.

[image]

Both option's default value is *10 seconds*.

Setting this value to *Never* will allow you to have keyboard enlighten all the time. Even with this setting you will be, however, able to permanently turn it off (and on again) using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

For more information see [user manual](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/pl/pl/plbsdt1/latitude-12-7290-laptop/latitude_7290_om/system-configuration-screen-options?guid=guid-d6f5377f-d831-4f94-befe-74693de8cf12&lang=en-us).